# Linux ipv4 forwarding not working as expected

Tags: linux-networking

I wanna use my raspberry pi as a intermediate router to access other LANs. Something like the following.

```
──────────────────────vpn 10.1.4.x─┐
                                   │
router 10.1.1.1────────────pi4b 10.1.1.42─────────>pc 10.1.1.43
      │
      ├───────────────────────────────────────────>tv
      │
      ├───────────────────────────────────────────>ps5
      │
      └───────────────────────────────────────────>etc...
```

So I enabled ipv4 forwarding in pi4b kernel.

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 1
```

On pi there is a default route to router(`10.1.1.1`). And pc has default route set to pi(`10.1.1.42`). Router's routing tables I don't have access, but I assume nothing special. It's a [Redmi AX6](https://xiaomi-mi.com/wifi-routers/redmi-ax6-router/), SSH not available.

But then I cannot access internet on my pc.

```
magrathea:~ jeffwhen$ traceroute 223.5.5.5
traceroute to 223.5.5.5 (223.5.5.5), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  * pi4b (10.1.1.42)  2.248 ms *
 2  xiaoqiang (10.1.1.1)  2.292 ms  1.317 ms  1.258 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
```

What did I do wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

---

Another piece of info which might be helpful: after adding masquerade in nat `POSTROUTING` chain, I can access internet on my pc. I think this means the pc does send everything through my raspberry pi. But why is masquerading necessary?

Comment: What is the routing table on the PC? What is the routing table on the Pi? What is the routing table on your router?

Comment: @vidarlo pc has default route to pi. And pi has default route to router. Router I can't access it routing table.
```

Comment: Does the Pi have two interfaces?

Comment: @vidarlo Not yet.

Comment: My plan is connect to office VPN on pi, then nat certain traffic to vpn link by masquerading. But I haven't started those configurations. I figure I have to be able to access internet via my router first.

Answer (score 1):

When your Pi gets a package that is not handled directly, it probably issues a ICMP route redirect, telling your PC to use 10.1.1.1 directly. This however doesn't work very well; it's a security risk, so many modern operating systems ignore them.

The proper solution is one of two:

- Have one router per subnet
- Have a route explicitly declared on the client.

### One router per subnet

Configure the network between your Pi and your PC to a different subnet than the rest of your LAN, e.g. 10.1.2.0/24. Your Pi will then have a default route with gw 10.1.1.1, and 10.1.4.0/24 with some gateway.

Any machines behind the Pi will simply have 10.1.2.0/24 with Pi as gateway.

### Declare route on client

Configure your Pi to have a IP in the 10.1.1.0/24-subnet. Do not set it as default gateway on any PC's; they should all have 10.1.1.1.

Add a route to 10.1.4.0/24 via the Pi. On windows this can be done with

```
route ADD 10.1.4.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.1.1.42
```

Use `route -p ADD...` to persist the route across reboots.

Comment: This is very detailed. Thank you. So I tried to capture the ICMP redirect in wireshark using expression `icmp.type == 5`. But I couldn't get any. Why is that?

Comment: I'll admit it's a bit of a shot from the hip, based on expirience ;)